# Javascript to Hide/Show Div using buttons, HTML is in a rich text component in AEM, can't get it to work?

Tags: javascript, html, css, aem, adobe-exprience-manager

I cannot get this to work.

I have 2 buttons. I also have divs.
When I click 1 button, I want 1 div to show and for the other to be hidden.
When I click the other button, I want the opposite to happen.
They should both be hidden on default.

Javascript function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#button-one").click(function() {
    $("#div-one").hide();
    $("#div-two").show();
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#button-two").click(function() {
    $("#div-one").show();
    $("#div-two").hide();
  });
});
```

I have also tried $('#sdfsdfs').css('display', 'block'), and document.getElementById("fsdfsdf").style.display="block";

HTML extract:

```
  
      <div class="buttonOne">
        <button id="button-one" value="button one"> Button One </button>
      </div>
      <div class="buttonTwo">
        <button id="button-two" value="button two"> Button Two </button>
      </div>
      <div class="divOne" id="div-one" style="display: none;">
Some HTML
      </div>
      <div class="divTwo" id="div-two" style="display: none;">
Some HTML
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Code above is how it goes, ignore the names.

What happens is when I load the page, each div is set to display: none, which is fine, however the clicks do not change the display to show. I am editing the values of a rich text component in AEM as well if that changes anything.

I have 2 buttons. I also have divs.
When I click 1 button, I want 1 div to show and for the other to be hidden.
When I click the other button, I want the opposite to happen.
They should both be hidden on default.

Code all is put above. Tried a lot of different ways of editing display, as well as setting the ID on css itself to display: none and editing on javascript.

Answer (score 0):

you have many mistakes that you can see if you want to.

your id for your second div that you want to show is not the same in your javascript `divTwo` vs. `div-two`

another is your last div isnt closed before you close the form.

another is that you have html inside a script tag? `</script>` is a closing tag.

and finally, its not a big deal but you should only have 1 ready js event. i left it in for you to show you that is still does work though.

here is working version of your code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>test</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.3.min.js" integrity="sha256-pvPw+upLPUjgMXY0G+8O0xUf+/Im1MZjXxxgOcBQBXU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
    
    <div class="buttonOne">
        <button id="button-one" value="button one"> Button One </button>
      </div>

      <div class="buttonTwo">
        <button id="button-two" value="button two"> Button Two </button>
      </div>

      <div class="divOne" id="div-one" style="display: none;">Some HTML 1</div>
      <div class="divTwo" id="div-two" style="display: none;">Some HTML 2</div>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function() {
          $("#button-one").click(function() {
            $("#div-one").hide();
            $("#div-two").show();
          });
        });

        $(document).ready(function() {
          $("#button-two").click(function() {
            $("#div-one").show();
            $("#div-two").hide();
          });
        });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The code is just a snippet hence the script tag, its a bit abstract and not actually what it looks like. The HTML in my actual code works fine Do you see anything wrong with the javascript itself and how I do the click function? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use fadeIn() to show the content, it gives a nice effect

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#button-one").click(function() {
        $("#div-one").hide();
        $("#div-two").fadeIn();
      });
    });

    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#button-two").click(function() {
        $("#div-one").fadeIn();
        $("#div-two").hide();
      });
    });

</script>
```